# Jquery mobile change value of a hidden text type input

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

When i change the value of a visible text input, it works great, but whent i change type="text" to type="hidden", it isn't working anymore.

Jquery code:

```
        <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (pos) {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var lat = pos.coords.latitude;
            var lng = pos.coords.longitude;
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            //reverse geocode the coordinates, returning location information.
            geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
                var result = results[0];
                var state = '';

                for (var i = 0, len = result.address_components.length; i < len; i++) {
                    var ac = result.address_components[i];

                    if (ac.types.indexOf('locality') >= 0) {
                        city = ac.long_name;
                    }
                }
                $('#city').val(city );  
                $('#city').textinput('disable');    
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Working HTML code:

```
<input name="city" id="city" value="" type="text">
```

This is the issue:

```
<input name="city" id="city" value="" type="hidden">
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: instead of use `$("#city").parent().addClass("ui-screen-hidden")` this will hide it but still accessible.

Comment: $('#city').val(city) should work.  But $('#city').textinput() will not work on a hidden input.  Try commenting out that extra line when you change it to a hidden element.